# How can I delete multiple rows with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity

I have this code but it doesn't work :

```
public bool DeleteAccess(int _UserID, IEnumerable<int> _ModulID)
{
    MPortalContext db=new MPortalContext();
    foreach (var item in _ModulID)
    {
        var validation = db.WebSite_PermissionDB.Where(x => x.UserID == _UserID && x.ModuleID == item);
        db.WebSite_PermissionDB.Remove(validation);
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
    return true;
}
```

my (_ModulID) is a collection of ids that i filter them and then with foreach  delete them but it doesn't work ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    MPortalContext db=new MPortalContext();
    foreach (var item in _ModulID)
    {
        var validation = db.WebSite_PermissionDB.Where(x => x.UserID == _UserID && x.ModuleID == item).FirstOrDefault();
        db.WebSite_PermissionDB.Remove(validation);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }  
    return true;
```

I forget use `.FirstOrDefault();` now correct. Thank friends.

Answer (score 2):

one way to delete is

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<WebSite_PermissionDB>(
  "DELETE FROM Users WHERE UserID = @userId  ",
  new [] { new SqlParameter("@userId ", 1) }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

First get the all entities that mathces with your condition, then use [`RemoveRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220170%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) method:

```
var entities = db.WebSite_PermissionDB
           .Where(x => x.UserID == _UserID && _ModulID.Contains(x.ModuleID));

db.WebSite_PermissionDB.RemoveRange(entities);

db.SaveChanges();
```

Also you might want to use `using` statement in order to make sure that your `DbContext` is `Disposed` properly.

```
using(MPortalContext db = new MPortalContext())
{ 
     ...
}
```

Comment: In my code :  dont know RemoveRange & Contains . But i use nameSpaces :using System.Data.Entity; & using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses; ??but dont know.

Answer (score 0):

```
var distinctResult = db.WebSite_PermissionDB.Distinct();
db.WebSite_PermissionDB.RemoveRange(db.WebSite_PermissionDB.Except(distinctResult));
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation for what this code sample does to your answer?

Comment: first select data by removing duplicate rows(Distinct method), then remove all rows unless selected data (Except method) in previous code.